# Initializing char Buffer with a string in c++

Tags: c++, buffer

I wan't to initialize a static char buffer with a string str in the code below but I am getting the following error :

> error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to >‘char’ in initialization

and if I use

```
static char buf[500] = str.c_str();
```

I get the following error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’
```

Below is my code :

```
std::string str = "<Version="+version+" Ret=\"false\"/>";
static char buf[500] = str;
int len=strlen(buf);
buf[len]='\0';
INFO("Static Buffer :: "<<buf);
```

Comment: Well, that's because programming by guessing does not work.

Comment: Your `buf[len]='\0'` is redundant: by definition, `len` is the index of the first `'\0'` that already exists within `buf`. All you're doing is replacing `'\0'` with `'\0'`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you cannot directly initialise a `char[]` from an `std::string`. It's just not possible. Even if you could, you would write `= str`, not `= { str }`.

So, you need to create the array first then assign the `std::string`'s contents to it manually. Sadly, arrays are not assignable, so you're going to have to use an "algorithm" to do it.

Here we go:

```
const std::string str = "Hello world";
static char buf[500] = {};
std::copy(
   // from the start of the string
   std::begin(str),

   // to the end of the string, or to 499 chars in, whichever comes first
   std::begin(str) + std::min(str.size(), sizeof(buf)),

   // into buf
   std::begin(buf)
);
```

Yuck.

If you can, and this is likely the case, *avoid it*.

If you really need a C-string with the `std::string`'s contents, just access `str.c_str()` whenever you need to. There is, in general, no need to keep a raw `char` array lying about, especially when you already have the right tool for the job doing that job.

Besides, as you are not *initialising* `buf` with that data, if it's function-`static`, this code probably does not have the intended effect.

Comment: It gives me the error: ‘begin’ is not a member of ‘std’ ..perhaps end and begin  can only be used for arrays and not strings

Comment: @yinyang You are using an old version of the standard to compile the code. Pre-C++11 doesn't have non-member `begin` and `end`. Add `-std=c++14` (or at least `std=c++11`) to the compiler options.

Comment: Or simply replace with `str.begin()`. A little research goes a long way: you could have figured this out from cppreference.com in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::string::copy()`.

```
std::string text = "Hello there!";
char* cStrText = new char[text.length()];

//Copy the string into the buffer
text.copy(cStrText, text.length(), 0);
```

Obviously, this performs a copy which may not be optimal. You might want to look into trying to move it.

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/copy/